# Can the UK general election be cancelled?

Tags: united-kingdom, election, parliament

The sh*t hits the fan. The Russia scandal blows up. Boris Johnson is photographed handing a suitcase of money to Nigel Farage. Vast swathes of the country is under water. A yellow weather warning is forecast for the week of the election. Can the election be cancelled?

If so, who cancels it? Can *anyone* cancel it? And what happens next? Does parliament go back to sitting as it was before?

Comment: Convince the supreme court to make up a new law,as long as you can think of a suitable peg to hang it on

Comment: @Displayname That's not how the Supreme Court works; they can't invent the law.

Comment: @Dan Scally they really can. While rare, activist "interpretation" (which actually can occur at any level; in this case the SC will be neccesary) is often the judges legeslating with a convinient hook to hang it on.

Comment: @Displayname can you cite an example?

Comment: @Dan Scally, well obviously whatever example I give you will likely just say 'well the experts ruled that's the law'. But to illustrate  the principal in an inadvertent manner at least - every time a higher court overalls a lower one on a matter of law, one of them has decided the law of the land not according to the law as legislated.... Of course that's not deliberate (at least not probably) but it is the same end result.

Comment: @Displayname That's not legislating, or inventing a law. That's deciding exactly what legislators meant when they drafted a law, or how the law as it stands should be applied in a specific case (the obvious implication being where there is conflict or uncertainty in the law). This scenario is different; the situation is absolutely clear, there is no provision in UK law for a General Election to be cancelled. Being nothing to clarify, the SC cannot possibly simply create new legislation giving the government the power to cancel the election. Perhaps we should move this to a question?

Comment: @Dan Scully I am aware that they can't make up stuff without an existing law to pretend that it meant that (actually they can, with common law, but we won't go into that) indeed, to repeat part of my first comment 'as long as you can think of a suitable peg to hang it on'.